# Optimizing webpack bundle size - Can firestore be initialized without importing RTDB?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using webpack to compile a preact / firestore application, and firebase overall is contributing 1.7 MB to the size of my compiled bundle.  I am attempting to reduce this number.

The realtime database and storage together contribute about 750 kb to the bundle size.  As I am not using the realtime database and storage at all, I would like to be exclude these from the bundle.  I suspect, but am not certain, that if I stop calling

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
require("firebase/firestore");
```

and instead do something to the effect of

```
import auth from 'firebase/auth';
require("firebase/firestore");
```

that this would remove the unwanted submodules from my bundle.  But, I can't get rid of my firebase import right now, as I am calling

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

as per the documentation.  Can I initialize firestore without calling firebase.initializeApp?

Answer (score 3):

The [web setup page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) for Firebase tells you what is optional and required:

> You can reduce the amount of code your app uses by just including the
>   features you need. The individually installable components are:
>
> - firebase-app - The core firebase client (required).
> - firebase-auth - Firebase Authentication (optional).
> - firebase-database - The Firebase Realtime Database (optional).
> - firebase-firestore - Cloud Firestore (optional).
> - firebase-storage - Cloud Storage (optional).
> - firebase-messaging - Firebase Cloud Messaging (optional).

You need to call initializeApp() no matter which parts of Firebase you intend to use.  That call indicates which project is in use.

Comment: Thanks Doug.  This change was necessary, but not sufficient, to get database and storage out of my bundle.  I am also depending on firebaseui at the moment, and it turns out that is directly depending on the parent firebase package.

Answer (score 1):

The last example from the [documentation on adding Firebase to your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app) shows how to do this:

```
var firebase = require("firebase/app");
require("firebase/auth");
require("firebase/firestore");

var config = {
  // ...
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

As Doug says, `initializeApp(...)` is always needed.